# Бинарное дерево строится слишком долго и приводит к крашу

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Бинарное дерево поиска быстро строится на случайной последовательности и хорошо работает, но на упорядоченной во возрастанию или убыванию последовательности работает очень долго и приводит к крашу программы. В чем причина всего этого? Привожу код:

```
#define SIZE 70000

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;
} node;

struct node * CreateTree(void){
    struct node *root;

    root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->data = NULL;
    root->parent = NULL;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    return root;
}

struct node * CreateNode(int data){
    struct node *p = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    p->data = data;
    p->left = NULL;
    p->right = NULL;
    p->parent = NULL;
    return p;
}

void TreeDestroy(struct node *root){
    if(root){
        TreeDestroy(root->left);
        TreeDestroy(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

void TreeInsert(struct node *root, struct node *z){
    struct node *y = NULL;
    struct node *x = root;

    while(x != NULL){
        y = x;
        if(z->data < x->data)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }
    z->parent = y;
    if(y == NULL)
        root = z;
    else{
        if(z->data < y->data)
            y->left = z;
        else
            y->right = z;
    }
}

void genOrderedSeq(int *array){
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        array[i] = i;
}

int main() {
    int seq[SIZE];
    struct node *tree;
    struct node *tmp;

    /*Упорядоченная последовательность*/
    genOrderedSeq(seq);
    std::cout << "*** Ordered Sequence ***" << std::endl;
    tree = CreateTree();
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        tmp = CreateNode(seq[i]);
        TreeInsert(tree, tmp);
    }
    TreeDestroy(tree);
    return 0;
}
```

Выполнение кода на идеоне: https://ideone.com/kpJezs

Comment: Самопальное бинарное дерево и C++. Что-то тут не так. map же есть.

Comment: От С++ там только std::cout и объявление автоматической переменной в области видимости цикла.

Comment: И маллок. Уж сколько раз твердили, что в c++ для работы с памятью нужно мспользовать new|delete

Comment: Столяров о ненужности C++ http://www.stolyarov.info/guestbook

Comment: Видим, что обработка случайной последовательности завершилась корректно, и началось формирование дерева из упорядоченной последовательности. https://ideone.com/kpJezs Может быть, дело в том, что из-за отсутствия балансировки образуется лиана? Или не хватает стека? Я же туда еще и массив закинул. Но уменьшение длины последовательности с 70к до 50к не помогло.

Comment: @gbg: "О ненужности тега C++ в вопросе о C"

Comment: Цитата из инфы по ссылке `В каком направлении должен развиваться С++ ?

Теперь уже, видимо, ни в каком. Нужен другой язык, который займёт нишу языка произвольного уровня, в отличие от существующих языков уровня низкого (asm/*, plain C) или высокого (всё остальное).` Смотрю, наши ряды растут.

Comment: Работает долго, поскольку при упорядоченной последовательности дерево вырождается в список. Поэтому время вставки всех элементов O(n ^ 2). / Почему у них валится -- не знаю. У меня `(Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-63-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 21:42:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
g++.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
)` проработала (для 70000) 10.4 сек. и нормально завершилась.

Comment: Да, пихать упорядоченные данные в дерево без балансировки нельзя, однако мне надо замерить скорость построения дерева (лианы) и на них тоже. Поэтому очень хочу разобраться в причине падения.

Comment: Если вы пишете серьёзное, недетское дерево, вам, возможно, придётся отказаться от рекурсивных алгоритмов и посмотреть на итеративные обходы дерева да хоть в том же Кнуте.

Comment: @VladD, у ТС как раз не рекурсивный алгоритм. / А пмшет Столяров не о ненужности C++ вообще, а  плохом **современном** C++ и проблемах с STL.

Comment: @avp: функция `TreeDestroy` вроде бы рекурсивна, на ней, кажется, и вылетало.

Comment: @VladD, точно (не углядел). Тогда вполне возможно, хотя что же это за размер стека на идеоне?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код - это что-то среднее между C-кодом и C++ - кодом. Вы должны определиться, либо вы пишите на C и, например, используете `malloc` для динамического выделения памяти для объектов, либо на C++ и используете оператор `new` вместо функции `malloc`.

Проблема вашей программы связана с рекурсивным вызовом функции `TreeDestroy` самой себя.

```
void TreeDestroy(struct node *root){
    if(root){
        TreeDestroy(root->left);
        TreeDestroy(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}
```

Когда входные данные уже упорядочены, то выстраивается максимальная глубина дерева и, соответственно максимальная цепочка вызовов функции.
Значение

```
#define SIZE 70000
```

достаточно большое.

Я думаю, вам следует заменить рекурсивное удаление узлов дерева, на итерационное.

Ниже показана демонстрационная программа, в которой используется итерационное удаление узлов дерева. Я внес некоторые незначительные коррективы в дизайн вашего дерева, которые упрощают демонстрацию функции удаления узлов.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;
};

void TreeInsert( node * &root, int value )
{
    if ( !root )
    {
        root = new node { value, nullptr, nullptr, root };
    }
    else
    {
        node **current = &root;
        node *parent = root;
        while ( *current != nullptr )
        {
            parent = *current;
            if ( value < ( *current )->data ) current = &( *current )->left;
            else current = &( *current )->right;
        }

        *current = new node { value, nullptr, nullptr, parent };
    }
}    

void TreeDestroy( node * &root )
{
    node *parent = root;

    while ( parent )
    {
        if ( parent->left == nullptr && parent->right == nullptr )
        {
            node *tmp = parent;
            parent = parent->parent;
            if ( parent != nullptr )
            {
                if ( parent->left == tmp ) parent->left = nullptr;
                else parent->right = nullptr;
            }

            //std::cout << "Deleting node " << tmp->data << std::endl;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else if ( parent->left != nullptr )
        {
            parent = parent->left;
        }
        else
        {
            parent = parent->right;
        }
    }

    root = parent;
}    

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 70000;

    node *tree = nullptr;

    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) TreeInsert( tree, i );

    TreeDestroy( tree );
}
```

Учтите, что сама операция выделения памяти для столь большого числа участков памяти такого маленького размера, занимает много времени. Так что я не рекомендую при запуске моей демонстрационной программы с помощью онлайнового компилятора раскомментировать строчку

```
//std::cout << "Deleting node " << tmp->data << std::endl;
```

Лучше это делать для меньших значений переменной `SIZE`.:)

Comment: а совет не использовать `malloc` в C++ это принципиально или просто "для чистоты расы"?

Comment: @avp  Если это не связано с какими-то проблемами интеграции программы с модулями, написанными на других языках, то я не вижу никаких серьезных аргументов в пользу использования malloc вместо оператора new/

Comment: Серьезных и в самом деле нет. Только `realloc` (если по логике задачи он может понадобиться). / Кстати, а как Вы считаете, почему в C++ его нет? (только не надо отсылать в гугл за пространными и зачастую невразумительными статьями),

Comment: @avp В какой-то своей книге Страуструп давал разъяснение, почему он отказался от realloc. Если память не изменяет, то главный тезис против этой функции состоял в том , что она ненадежная.

Comment: Спасибо. Хотя, вот такие объяснения  мне и кажутся невразумительными. Естественно, я не имею в виду просто взять realloc из libc и во всех ситуациях  использовать его, понятно, что была бы нужна реализация, учитывающая специфику ООП.

Comment: @avp К сожалению, я не могу найти источник, чтобы его процитировать. Помню лишь, что все сводилось к небезопасности функции и к совету использовать стандартные контейнеры, которые делают эту работу за вас.